# Selecting list a item if it has child list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of links. I need to append something to a link if the parent 
**LI** that contain another list. Having difficulty selecting the top level and not the ones in the children.

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $('#container > ul > li').has('ul').each(function() {
   $(this).find('a').append('zzz');
 });
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mfxr5kt3/)

Comment: Use `$(this).find('>a')` or [`$(this).children('a')`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crazy idea... you could do this purely with CSS by targeting the `<a>` tags that are not the last child in their parent `<li>`.

```css
#container > ul > li > a:not(:last-child):after {
  content: 'zzz';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise, you can use a similar selector in jQuery

```
$('#container > ul > li > a:not(:last-child)').append('zzz');
```

Comment: Well... 'zzz' was obviously a placeholder. But I really like jQuery solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your question states, I would filter the anchors for parents that have a list.

```
 $('a')
  .filter(function() { return $(this).parent().find('ul').length; })
  .each(function() {
    $(this).append('zzz');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**Demo**](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/JvLQWq)

You try this,

```
$('#container > ul > li').has('ul').each(function() {
       $(this).find('li').next().append('<li><a href="#">My new Tag</a></li>');
     });
```